# How to record if and when my Macbook is opened

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I like to know when my family goes on my Macbook for numerous reasons. Is there a way to record when or if people go on my Macbook when I leave it laying around?

Comment: Maybe logs? Not sure. You could set times that they are allowed to go on in Parental Controls, except I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: Safest overall would be to not let them know your login details; set up their own [non-admin] accounts or a guest account.

Comment: also enable FileVault 2

Comment: @Tetsujin no, that's not an option. I don't want to come across like I have something to hide.

Comment: You don't need to "have something to hide" in order to want to make sure that others don't accidentally disturb or delete your stuff. Separate logins that other people don't know are basic security and safety of your data... and theirs. Separate logins for every user of a machine is just core, basic practice that all computer-savvy people do.

Comment: So, how do I log when these non-admin accounts are logged into?

Comment: "Switch user." You can have multiple active logins.

Comment: Set the machine so that every time it's closed, it requires password login. It's in the preferences. One of the choices will be "switch user." You can also have a "guest" account for truly temporary use (that deletes all traces every time the guest logs out), though separate user logins for each potential persistent user is the best approach. Remember that inadequate security for any user of the machine is a huge security hole for ALL users of the machine. The whole family is safer if everybody uses proper login and password hygiene, starting with separate user accounts.

Comment: Where is the log file when people switch users?

Answer (score 1):

Try the command `last`

It will show you every login since the last reboot.

Open Terminal and just type (using my dev xserve as an example)

```
[admin@xserve1 ~]$ last
admin      pts/0    allans-imac.home       Wed Mar  2 23:20   still logged in

utx.log begins Wed Mar  2 23:20:07 EST 2016
[admin@xserve1 ~]$
```

This would be correct since nobody but me (the admin) had logged into it.